# How to recover grants for root user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I accidentally removed all privileges for root user. How can I recover it ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this part of the MySQL-Documentation, they've dedicated a whole chapter to this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

First, [start MySQL with --skip-grant-tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html)
Next, run the following query:
`UPDATE mysql.user SET
Select_priv = 'Y',

          Insert_priv = 'Y',
          Update_priv = 'Y',
          Delete_priv = 'Y',
          Create_priv = 'Y',
            Drop_priv = 'Y',
          Reload_priv = 'Y',
        Shutdown_priv = 'Y',
         Process_priv = 'Y',
            File_priv = 'Y',
           Grant_priv = 'Y',
      References_priv = 'Y',
           Index_priv = 'Y',
           Alter_priv = 'Y',
         Show_db_priv = 'Y',
           Super_priv = 'Y',
Create_tmp_table_priv = 'Y',
     Lock_tables_priv = 'Y',
         Execute_priv = 'Y',
      Repl_slave_priv = 'Y',
     Repl_client_priv = 'Y',
     Create_view_priv = 'Y',
       Show_view_priv = 'Y',
  Create_routine_priv = 'Y',
   Alter_routine_priv = 'Y',
     Create_user_priv = 'Y',
           Event_priv = 'Y',
         Trigger_priv = 'Y',
max_questions = 0,
          max_updates = 0,
      max_connections = 0,
 max_user_connections = 0
WHERE user = 'root'`

Finally, run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and restart MySQL

If you need to reset the password as well, follow the instructions in the link above.